# Android DBFlow does not save objects

Tags: android, save, dbflow

I have a database like this:

```
@Database(name = QuestionDatabase.NAME, version = QuestionDatabase.VERSION)
public class QuestionDatabase {

    public static final String NAME = "QuestionDatabase"; // we will add the .db extension

    public static final int VERSION = 1;
}
```

and a table like this:

```
@Table(database = QuestionDatabase.class)
public class Question extends BaseModel {
    @PrimaryKey
    public int localID;
    @Column
    public int Id;
    @Column
    public String Answer;
    @Column
    public String ImageURL;
    @Column
    public boolean IsFavorite;
    @Column
    public boolean IsSolved;
}
```

and an asynctask to retrive data from server:

```
public class QuestionRetriever extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Integer> {

    private Activity callerActivity;
    private QuestionAdapter questionsAdapter;
    private List<Question> callerQuestions;

    private Integer pageSize = 10;

    public QuestionRetriever(Activity callerActivity, QuestionAdapter questionsAdapter, List<Question> questions){
        this.callerActivity = callerActivity;
        this.questionsAdapter = questionsAdapter;
        this.callerQuestions = questions;
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... pageNumbers) {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://192.168.1.33:313/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        QuestionWebService service = retrofit.create(QuestionWebService.class);

        Call<List<Question>> call = service.getQuestionsPaged(pageNumbers[0].toString(), pageSize.toString());

        try {
            Response<List<Question>> excecuted = call.execute();
            List<Question> questions = excecuted.body();
            FastStoreModelTransaction
                    .insertBuilder(FlowManager.getModelAdapter(Question.class))
                    .addAll(questions)
                    .build();
            callerQuestions.addAll(questions);
            callerActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    questionsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

            //Get TotalQuestionCount if not yet
            if (((StatefulApplication) callerActivity.getApplication()).getQuestionCount() == -1){
                Call<Integer> call2 = service.getQuestionsSize();
                try {
                    ((StatefulApplication) callerActivity.getApplication()).setQuestionCount(call2.execute().body());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        //TODO: show loader
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        //TODO: hide loader
    }
}
```

as you see every thing seems ok and eve after running `FastStoreModelTransaction` nothing wrong happens. no errors.

the init job is done in splash screen activity like this:

```
private void initializeEveryRun() {
        //Initializing DBFlow
        //DBFlow needs an instance of Context in order to use it for a few features such as reading from assets, content observing, and generating ContentProvider.
        //Initialize in your Application subclass. You can also initialize it from other Context but we always grab the Application Context (this is done only once).
        FlowManager.init(new FlowConfig.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build());
    }
```

any idea about what should cause this problem or any solution to try?
TG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer!!!

As you see in the model, the `Id` is the identifier of the object retrieved from server and `LocalId` is the auto-increment identifier that is stored locally. This was the problem. I've used the `Id` field as Primary Key and added a field named `OnlineId` for server side identifer and everything is ok now.

Is this a bug or I was using that wrong?

TG.

Answer (score 1):

This is not execute transaction, it's just transaction creation.

As you can see it this test [DBFlow - FastModelTest.kt](https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow/blob/4.0.0-beta5/dbflow-tests/src/test/java/com/raizlabs/android/dbflow/test/sql/fast/FastModelTest.kt).

`FastStoreModelTransaction
                    .insertBuilder(FlowManager.getModelAdapter(Question.class))
                    .addAll(questions)
                    .build();`

---

You must execute your transaction like this :

`FlowManager.getDatabase(QuestionDatabase.class).executeTransaction(<<YourTransaction>>);`

Otherwise, if you already had a DatabaseWrapper instance you can do `<<YourTransaction>>.excute(<<YourDatabaseWrapper>>);`.